# React Development mode react script display errors in bundle instead of actual component in source map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My application display errors inside bundle.js instead of actual component.

I have verified in devtools -> preference --> enable javascript source maps (checked)

Below are other details

1. My app not using webpack.
2. I use "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
3. use command npm run start to start the application in development mode.

on some error in Component.js browser gives logs of bundle.js (while is difficult to read) instead of line from Component.js

Any help here is appreciated.

1. Application not using webpack but default react-scripts configuration
2. I have verified in devtools -> preference --> enable javascript source maps (checked)
   [error screenshot mentioning bundle.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hwxM.png)

Attached image above, error is in component named DateRangePickerSideBySide, however browser consoles display error inside bundle.js at some line instead of line from component.

application is running on localhost:3000 with default react-scritps npm start command.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)